# MongoDB - add last element of array to existing array in other field

Tags: mongodb

How can I take the last element in an array and add it to an array in another field, in the same document? As below, I want to add "z" to `field2`.

```
{
   field1: ["x","y","z"],
   field2: []
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Updates with Aggregation Pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/), which is available in MongoDB versions starting from **MongoDB 4.2**

**Update Query will look something like this**

```
db.collection.update({},[
  {
    $set: {
      field2: {
        $concatArrays: [
          "$field2",
          [
            {
              $arrayElemAt: [
                "$field1",
                {
                  $subtract: [
                    {
                      $size: "$field1"
                    },
                    1
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

The above query will take the last element from the `field1` array and add it to the `field2` array.

**PS:** If you just want to see the working of aggregation pipeline used in the update, you see it [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kxzT918iKHa)

Comment: Instead of `$arrayElemAt: ["$field1", { $subtract: [{ $size: "$field1" }, 1] }]` you can simply use `$arrayElemAt: ["$field1", -1]` - or in Mongo 4.4 just `$last: "$field1"`